Vite: importing dayjs works in dev mode, but does not work in production
I just created React + TypeScript + Vite project which uses dayjs library.
I imported dayjs by namespace import:
import * as dayjs from "dayjs";

...

(params) => dayjs(params?.value).format("MM/DD hh:mm")

This works in dev mode, but does not work in production(building generates some errors).
However, using default import solves this problem, import dayjs from "dayjs" works in both dev and prod mode.
My Question is:

Why namespace import works in dev mode, but does not work in prod?
Why default import works in both dev and prod mode?

I guess Vite(using different build tool in dev(esbuild) and prod(Rollup)) makes this issue. Anyone knows why this happens?

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}

vite.config.json
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})

package.json
{
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "format": "npx prettier --write src",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.0",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.18.4",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.18.4",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.20.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.17",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.14.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.14.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.55.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "prettier": "3.1.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.0.8"
  }
}

